# How to locate element by partial XPath

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Trying to locate a text input box by its Xpath which dynamically changes some of the last elements every time the page is loaded.

This is the HTML for it.

```
<input type="text" value="" name="client[phones_attributes][1654091616613][number]" id="client_phones_attributes_1654091616613_number" class="placeholderField-input">
```

It's XPath is //*[@id="client_phones_attributes_1654091616613_number"]

The numbers change every load. I tried locating it by using this line but it didn't find it.

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@id, 'client_phones_attributes_')]")
```

Comment: Try to use [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#waits)

Comment: The page is already loaded I've done inputs before this point.

Comment: Then check if your `input` node located inside an `iframe`

Answer (score -1):

you need to search as:

**on last versions of selenium:**

```
search = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//input[contains(@id, "client_phones_attributes_")]')
```

**on your version**

```
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id, 'client_phones_attributes_')]")
```

Comment: Still doesn't fix the problem though.